# using the magic __set() method with 2D arrays

Tags: php, class, multidimensional-array, magic-methods

If I have the following registry class:

```
Class registry 
{
    private $_vars;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_vars = array();
    }

    public function __set($key, $val)
    {
        $this->_vars[$key] = $val;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->_vars[$key]))
            return $this->_vars[$key];
    }

    public function printAll()
    {
        print "<pre>".print_r($this->_vars,true)."</pre>";
    }
}

$reg = new registry();

$reg->arr = array(1,2,3);
$reg->arr = array_merge($reg->arr,array(4));

$reg->printAll();
```

Would there be an easier way to push a new item onto the 'arr' array? 
This code: 'array[] = item' doesn't work with the magic set method, and I couldn't find any useful info with google. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Spoonface, what do you want `_vars` to look like after the two `__set()` calls? `array("arr" => array(1,2,3,4))`?

Comment: aye that's right, it should look like: _vars => array('arr' => array(1,2,3,4)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have:

```
$reg = new registry();
$reg->arr = array(1,2,3);
$reg->arr = 4;
```

And you're expecting:

```
Array
(
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

All you need to do is update your `__set` method to:

```
public function __set($key, $val){
  if(!array_key_exists($key, $this->_vars)){
    $this->_vars[$key] = array();
  }
  $this->_vars[$key] = array_merge($this->_vars[$key], (array)$val);
}
```

Comment: hiya, that's a pretty good solution to the problem, thanks very much!

Comment: It works in limited circumstances, though. It seems it's impossible to use __set to update arrays.

Comment: @Vlad, I'm doubtful that is the case. If you'd like to paste an example, I'd be willing to help you work through it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to alter the definition of __get() so that it returns by reference:

```
public function &__get($key) {
  return $this->_vars[$key];
}
```